# What is correct method to access Laravel logs from application start.php

Tags: php, laravel, logging

Sorry if this seems a dumb question but I am learning how the Laravel framework operates.
I have a working web app that uses the Laravel framework. The log file is set in backend/app/start/global.php

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Error Logger
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will configure the error logger setup for the application which
| is built on top of the wonderful Monolog library. By default we will
| build a rotating log file setup which creates a new file each day.
|
*/

$logFile = 'log-'.php_sapi_name().'.txt';

Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
Log::info('Log file set to '.$logFile);
```

The last line `Log::info()` I added to the file and it works ok.
However i need to add similar info logging messages to backend/bootstrap/start.php. I now want to add a `Log::info()` statement. 
I have reference to the Laravel application via the line in start.php

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
```

So my question is; if I am using the Laravel framework what is the correct way to get a reference to the Laravel "Log" defined in global.php. So that I can add a line such as:

```
Log::info('Using Environment '.$key);
```

Comment: What version of Laravel is this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to get a reference to `Log` class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

Comment: So is this a static class? I added the "use" statement and i had this error in the php log.  'Fatal error:  Call to a member function info() on null in \backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 208'

Comment: Is this something to do with the order that the framework calls global.php and start.php

Answer (score 0):

Using `$app['log']->info('Stuff you want to log')` should work but I don't think that's a good idea.

This file exists only to create the "app" but you shouldn't need to do anything inside since the config files aren't even loaded that's why you can't use Facades here, no config file => no Facades.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That code generated same error as before so it looks like I cant log anything in the start.php. Side question: is there some Laravel documentation that documents how and in what order the framework calls the files; start, global etc? This might help work out where I can log information.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? You can see the request life cycle in the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/lifecycle

Comment: Perfect! I can find my way from there.

Comment: So what's your Laravel version?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.6.23.  I also found this excellent article that really helps understand when parts of the framework come into play. From there I can better understand when specific objects are available. [link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/52/understanding-the-request-lifecycle)

Comment: Consider up voting and mark my answer as solved if it helped